# PyCharm test right-click run: builtins.tuple AttributeError object has no attribute

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

After an update and some project import, something very weird happens to my tests once run from Pycharm. I already fixed the general unittest runner config, but I am not being able to do it when running single tests, both in the config and just with a right click, which is quite comfortable.

Here is a very simple example code:

```
import unittest

class TestTheTester(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.name = "TestTheTester"

    def test_unittest(self):
        self.assertEqual("TestTheTester", self.name)
```

Running it from the Shell:

```
python3 -m unittest tests/test_the_tester.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Running it from PyCharm by right-click on it (option `"Run 'Python test in tests...'`):

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /snap/pycharm-community/252/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_trialtest_runner.py --path /home/user123/development/Project456/tests/test_the_tester.py
Testing started at 10:26 ...
Launching trial with arguments --reporter=teamcity /home/user123/development/Project456/tests/test_the_tester.py in /home/user123/development/Project456/tests/


Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: builtins.tuple: (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'TestTheTester' object has no attribute 'name'"), <traceback object at 0x7fc59e432f00>)
```

The Run/Debug Configuration it creates is:

- 'Python tests' one
- Autodetect's **Target** '`Script path`' to `/home/user123/development/Project456/tests/test_the_tester.py`
- **Python interpreter** `Project Default` (`/usr/bin/python3.8`)
- **Working directory** `/home/user123/development/Project456/tests/`
- Both options '**Add content roots to PYTHONPATH**' and '**Add source roots to PUTHONPATH**' selected

Comment: were you able to identify the issue? I get the same error.

Comment: I had to re-define all the run the PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations for the tests... It makes no sense, but I did not find any way to fix the previous configurations, so, just defined a new one working, and then cloned that. 
Sorry I did not find any better way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you found out the solution though, I fixed the same problem after changing test files' name to start with 'test_' and initiating a class for the test in "setUp" method.

In my case, my test code which worked perfectly didn't work at all after install some libraries with the error message below:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: builtins.tuple:
```

I hope you solved the issue already!

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't really fixed it in an elegant manner, I just did what mentioned in this comment (above): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69581980/pycharm-test-right-click-run-builtins-tuple-attributeerror-object-has-no-attrib/73368381#comment126268651_69581980